# JScript Regex XML attribute using Sub-Match?

Tags: regex, xml, attributes, jscript

I have the following text I'm searching:

```
<add key="Directory" value="" />
```

And this is my regex:

```
add key=\x22Directory\x22 value=\x22([^\x22]*)\x22
```

My desired output is:

```
<add key="Directory" value="blue" />
```

But, with what I have, it seems to be selecting the whole tag and producing:

```
<blue />
```

But, according to regex101, it shouldn't be. What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried:

```
value=\x22([^\x22]*)\x22
```

But, that returns:

```
<add key="Directory" blue />
```

Regex101 is telling me the following. It matches and notices the first capturing group but yet is still replacing the entire value=""

[image: regex submatch]

Comment: The "producing" part of your post isn't currently showing up so it's hard to know what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, updated my question.

Comment: Don't use RegEx to parse XML. Use the DOM and XPath/CSS selectors if possible or another XML Api if needed.

Comment: @ThW, I agree but sadly I am writing a batch file and this is the best thing I found. jrepl.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). So something like this, where the spot you're trying to pinpoint is preceded and proceeded by the lookaround text:

```
(?<=<add key="Directory" value=")[^"]*(?=" />)
```

Tweak to your liking, but that's the basic idea.

EDIT:

Since using jscript, try something like this (tweaking the substitution):

```
var re = /add key=\x22Directory\x22 value=\x22([^\x22]*)\x22/; 
var str = '<add key="Directory" value="" />'; //<- sample input. it could be your whole XML doc.
var subst = 'add key="Directory" value="Blue"'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

or...

```
var re = /(add key=\x22Directory\x22 value=\x22)[^\x22]*(\x22)/; 
var str = '<root>\n    <someOtherElement/>\n    <add key="Directory" value="" />\n</root>';
var subst = '$1Blue$2'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Hmm that seems to result in a syntax error in regular expression: http://i.imgur.com/JnQRQgA.png

Comment: Your test tool may not support lookbehind. What technology will you ultimately be running the expression in? .NET will work fine.

FWIW - The verbatim expression ran great in Expresso, which is what I use for testing.

Comment: I will  be using JScript (jrepl specifically) if that helps in anyway. I've been testing with regex101 which also complained of syntax errors. I was able to fix the syntax errors by removing the < you had in the first lookaround.But, it also didn't work

Comment: Edited my answer. If you use your original expression that matches the whole thing, you can just have the substitution include the original value + your added attribute value.

Comment: I also included a second option where you invert what you capture, then perform the substation on what's in-between via:

'$1Blue$2' where $1 is the first group you capture in parenthesis "Blue" is the value you want to stick in-between and $2 is the second group you capture via the modified expression (whose parenthesis have changed since the original expression like "(add key=\x22Directory\x22 value=\x22)[^\x22]*(\x22)").